# How to use an image file that is locally downloaded via @resource, as an icon in a `input` element

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have [this script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14863-greasyfork-add-a-send-pm-to-user-button-in-greasyfork-profile-pages) for greasemonkey to add a `send PM to user` "button" *(which is essentially an `input` element)*
to e.g. this page https://greasyfork.org/en/users/2160-darkred
My code that currently adds the "button" successively is:

```
var referenceNode = document.querySelector('div.width-constraint:nth-child(2) > h2:nth-child(1)');
var a = document.createElement('input');
referenceNode.appendChild(a);

a.style.padding = '0px 12px';
a.setAttribute('type', 'image');
a.setAttribute('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/ZU0xS0c.jpg');
```

I want to change the code, so that the button icon is downloaded once (as `@resource`, instead).

So, based on [this](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40resource) and [this](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceURL#Examples), I tried to change my code into:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @grant       GM_getResourceURL
// @resource    icon http://i.imgur.com/ZU0xS0c.jpg
// ==/UserScript==

var referenceNode = document.querySelector('div.width-constraint:nth-child(2) > h2:nth-child(1)');
var a = document.createElement('input');
referenceNode.appendChild(a);

a.style.padding = '0px 12px';
a.setAttribute('type', 'image');
a.setAttribute('src', GM_getResourceURL('icon') );
```

The problem is that the button now doesn't use the `icon` file
*(its displayed as text: '`Submit Query`' instead)*.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute`, assign directly as per [GM_getResourceURL documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceURL): `a.src=GM_getResourceURL('icon')`

Comment: @wOxxOm: Unfortunately, the issue remains.

Comment: Both variants work here with Tampermonkey/Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm: So, this must be a Firefox Nightly issue only (in FF43 it doesn't occur neither).  So I reported it here: https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2341. Thank you for your replies